# Java: Synchronizing socket input

Tags: java, php, multithreading, sockets, synchronize

My first attempt at writing a client for a php socket server and I'm running into a little trouble and I'm sort of being flooded with info!

With the server, we want an open connection, I want my client end to wait until it receives data before notifying the thread to start parsing the input-stream. Is this achievable without using a loop? I'd rather be able to call lock.notify().

I was also looking at NIO, is this a viable option for what I want? 
Here's the code I have so far, but again, I'm just trying to avoid the for(;;) and maybe even queue the received messages as they will most likely just be JSON

```
 Thread serverRecieve = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            for (;;) {
                if (in != null) {
                    String line;
                    while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                        sout(line);
                    }
                } else {
                    sout("inputstream is null! Waiting for a second to test again");
                }
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(WebManager.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(WebManager.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
});
```

Thanks guys!
PS: I did look through A LOT of socket threads on here but decided it would be easier just to ask what I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use a `while` loop and put a condition using `in != null` as:

```
    while(in == null){
       //wait for a second before checking the in stream again
       try {
            sout("inputstream is null! Waiting for a second to test again");
            Thread.sleep(1000);
       } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
          Logger.getLogger(WebManager.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
       }    
    }

     //now your in is available. Read the data and proceed
     String line = null;
     while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
          sout(line);
     }
```

The first `while` loop will terminate as soon `in` stream is available.

Comment: That works, but I suppose my real question is whether we can get rid of the loop altogether and have the stream notify of a message received, It's just that I don't know enough about Sockets to understand this.

Comment: @TFC You may another pattern e.g. `SocketChannel socketChannel = SocketChannel.open(); socketChannel.connect(new InetSocketAddress(url, port));
while(! socketChannel.finishConnect() ){
    //wait..and check    
}` but again its a polling mechanism to check whether  socket is available.

Answer (score 0):

How about creating dedicated subtype of `Runnable` for reading from socket, like this:

```
class Reader implements Runnable {

    private final Socket socket;
    private volatile boolean stopped;

    Reader(Socket socket) {
        this.socket = socket;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            while (true) {
                int in = socket.getInputStream().read();
                // process in here
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (!stopped) socket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public void stop() {
        try {
            stopped = true;
            socket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

class Client {
    private volatile Reader reader;
    void start() {
        reader = new Reader(new Socket(serverHost, serverPort));
        Thread readerThread = new Thread(reader, "Reader-thread");
        readerThread.start();
    }
    void stop() {
        Reader reader = this.reader;
        // reader.stop() will close socket making `run()` method finish because of IOException
        // reader.socket is final, thus we have proper visibility of it's values across threads
        if (reader != null) reader.stop();
    }
}
```